# Fantasy book series about two children climbing trees that take them to other worlds

Tags: story-identification, books

I’m having a really hard time remembering the name of a book series…
It was about two children who find trees that when climbed take them to other worlds. There were many different trees and each one went to a different world/place, I’m pretty sure the trees talked or something like to. It was an adventurous fantasy, not scientific.

Comment: My first thought was that this might be a slightly mis-remembered "The Magician's Nephew" (chronologically the first book in the Narnia series). My next thought was that it was about a Trumpalar Tree [goodreads link to the first](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6929466-the-riddle-of-the-trumpalar), of which there appear to be two books. If either of them are it, let me know and I will post this as an answer.

Comment: @Emma Thorgesen - Hi, welcome to the site. Please take a look at the check lists within [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and if you recall any further details about these books, then please edit them into your question. It would be particularly helpful to know in roughly which year you read these books, and when you think they might've been published.

Comment: I’ve read all the books in the  Narnia series multiple times (great books), so I know that it wasn’t The Magicians Nephew… the other book doesn’t look/sound like it either.
Thank very much for trying to help me though!

Answer (score 5):

Might this be ***[The Faraway Tree](https://www.goodreads.com/series/58850-the-faraway-tree)*** series by Enid Blyton...?

- Book 1: *[The Enchanted Wood](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17491.The_Enchanted_Wood)* (1939)
- Book 2: *[The Magic Faraway Tree](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/74998.The_Magic_Faraway_Tree)* (1943)
- Book 3: *[The Folk of the Faraway Tree](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/473623.The_Folk_of_the_Faraway_Tree)* (1946)
- Book 4: *[Up the Faraway Tree](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1036706.Up_the_Faraway_Tree)* (1985)

[The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faraway_Tree) provides an overview of the plot:

> The stories take place in an enchanted wood in which a gigantic magical tree grows – the eponymous 'Faraway Tree'. The tree is so tall that its topmost branches reach into the clouds and it is wide enough to contain small houses carved into its trunk. The wood and the tree are discovered by three children named Jo, Bessie and Fanny (later updated to Joe, Beth and Frannie), who move into a house nearby. They then go on adventures to the top of the tree.